# BroadcastReceiver: Activities get data from a Broadcast Activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have ActivityA which toggles BroadcastReceiver on/off. When the ActivityA toggles on/registers BroadcastReceiver can the other Activities get the broadcast? I don't want each activity to register a BroadcastReceiver, is there any way? When I exit ActivityA I don't unregister `broadcastTest`.

In my ActivityA I have this

```
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastTest = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // broadcast something here
           }
   }
```

How will for example ActivityB get the broadcast?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a process-wide BroadcastReceiver. So I think you should register/unregister your broadcastreceiver in your Application Object. Or you can declare it in your AndroidManifest.xml and the receiver decides whether to respond to that broadcast event.